# flutter tiktok like video preload

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter app where I am loading video URLs from firebase firestore and displaying them in a PageView vertically like tiktok using the video_player plugin. But there's a delay between the loading of the next videos and the previous videos and i want the next video to preload so that they are displayed sequentially with no delay.

- I have already tried flutter preload_page_view package and it is not working as it loads the next video while the current video is still playing and has problems.
- i tried allowImplicitScrolling: true, as suggested by someone on stackoverflow but I think it works for images and doesn't work for videos in my case.

Answer (score 0):

use preload_page_view combined with this https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector, when it's not being shown set the video play to false.